# Liferay, user can not see draft documents?

Tags: liferay-6

I am working with **Liferay 6.1** CE on tomcat6,

we have the following problem in the **document library**,
to upload a document and **mark it as a draft**, not visible to
creator and owner can not see draft document.

Only the site administrator can view the document.

Try to assign permissions to roles more, but I have not gotten to see the draft document again.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi. Check out this link: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/15019715.

Comment: I have the same problem using "kaleo workflow"
to refuse or withdraw the application through "kaleo workflow" the document is in draft status again only visible to the administrator of the site and the document creator can not see

Comment: Check out new version of liferay, 6.2. Maybe there this problem is solved.